# How does constructor injection work in TYPO3 Extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I just realized that TYPO3 Extbase can (in some situations?) inject dependencies even if you do not pass them to the constructor when you call e.g. `$objectManager->get(Foo::class)`? I am confused how and when this works. I could not find the answer myself by reading the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::getConstructorArguments()`.

It works as follows:

if

- argument was not supplied when calling `ObjectManager->get()` and
- there‘s no default value (in constructor signature, that‘s when `$argumentInformation['defaultValue']` is set) and
- the required argument is a class (that‘s when `$argumentInformation['dependency']` is set)

then this class will be instantiated and supplied as a parameter to the constructor call

Comment: I just answered how constructor injection works - if we‘re talking about injection in general Paul‘s suggestion to use `inject*` methods (rather than `@inject` annotations) might be preferable in many cases.

Comment: Are only certain classes injected via constructor injection or only those who implement the SingletonInterface?

What if I would define a domain model class as an obligatory constructor argurment – would Extbase create a fresh instance of this domain model class and inject it? What if this domain model class itself has obligatory constructor arguments? Would they be created on the fly regardless of whether they themself implement the SingletonInterface? Does this make sense?

I would make sense to me to inject classes that implement the SingletonInterface but anything else feels weird.

Comment: Does constructor injection work everywhere in Extbase land? Also if a domain model class has obligatory constructor arguments? Do they really also get injected if I e.g. call `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(BankAccount::class)` when `BankAccount` needs e.g. a `Person` and therefore has `Person $person` as an obligatory constructor argument?

Comment: `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` will never inject anything. You have to use `$this->objectManager->get()` where available or `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get()` otherwise.

Comment: The BankAccount->Person relation is usually not solved via constructor injection. I suppose you read up about extbase‘s way of modelling and persistence, e.g. [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/Index.html)

Comment: Regarding `SingletonInterface`: DI [complains](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/_container_8php_source.html#l00307) if you inject a Prototype into a Singleton.

Comment: Is it technically possible to inject Prototypes into Prototypes? Auto-Injecting Prototypes feels weird.

Comment: Well, I think we need to get terms straight first: In extbase world a prototype is just [anything except for singletons](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/2-BasicPrinciples/1-Object-oriented%20Programming-in-PHP.html#prototype). That‘s what I was referring to.

Comment: Yes, I was also referring to this.

Answer (score 2):

It's works in alot of classes in the Extbase Framework. You just have to add @inject annotation to the properties above the declaration.

```
/**
     * myRepository
     *
     * @var \TGM\Extension\Domain\Repository\MyRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $myRepository= NULL;
```

This works under the depencies which where told by undko like in ActionControllers, Models, Repositories, CommandController and so on.

Comment: Note that the `inject*` methods are faster than the `@inject` annotation. E.g. `public function injectMyRepository(\TGM\Extension\Domain\Repository\MyRepository $repository) {$this->myRepository = $repository;}`

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @paul-beck What exactly do you mean with `It's works in alot of classes in the Extbase Framework.`?